# Windows Server 2008 R2 Apps can't access the internet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 on my notebook and experiencing a strange issue. Internet Explorer and Firefox can access the internet. Apps like Tweetdeck, Blackberry Destop Manager and Word (publishing a blog to Wordpress) can't get to the internet. This happens on my network or others. Wired or wireless makes no difference. The firewall is off. It seemed to be intermittent, one day Tweetdeck would work the next it wouldn't (starting from boot not sleep or hibernate). I looked over the changes I had made to the system and had installed WinPCCap to play with Firesheep. I removed those with no effect.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Norman

Comment: How are you disabling the firewall for testing? Stop service, GUI, or shell?

Answer (score 2):

I just found it. IE got set to work off-line which impacts the other apps. I found it by trying One Note and it told me to check that setting.

Comment: That just seems wrong that IE has such a wide scope of control. Firefox must be using a lower API. I thought I tried IE since the problem started, but I must not have done that. Sorry about the mis-information that IE was working.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox: in about:config

set toolkit.networkmanager.disable to true.